# What java dependency required for Schema class?

Tags: schema

I am using wsc verion 22.0, and i could not find getGlobalDescribe in Schema class there, please can you tell which dependency I have to add for following statement.

map GlobalMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

Comment: Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: Are you getting any error?